# SQL selecting multiple stores

Tags: t-sql

I have created a stored procedure where I can select a singular store, but having trouble selecting multiple stores OR selecting a singular store. I know this can be easily achieved by an OR statement, I have just forgotten how to do it.

```
WHERE
    ISSUE_TYPE = 'T1'
AND
    TXT_03 = @STORE
AND
    ISSUE_STS IN ('C', 'N', 'I', 'D')
AND
    ENT_STAMP BETWEEN @DtFrom AND @DtTo
```

Comment: So provide sample data, stored procedure, what you have tried?

Comment: oh man, you need to post your code

Comment: What do you mean "singular store"? What store? Store as in a grocery or store as in a database? And why should it be a problem to select one or many groceries? If you select multiples by passing a list of IDs, values just pass a *single* value

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the IN statement like this:

your_column IN ('1', '2', '3', '4')

numbers can be the ids of your stores maybe?

Comment: I need to be able to select "All" or "ABC"

Comment: @TitoPaterson you need to write a proper question first. All or one isn't multiple or one. All actually means "ignore this column". *Don't* use a stored procedure in this case. Create a view and use different queries for each case. Or a single stored procedure to select specific stores and query against the view if you want all results. *Why* do you want a stored procedure in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can do below:

```
IF (@STORE IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    -- ...
    WHERE
        ISSUE_TYPE = 'T1'
    AND
        TXT_03 = @STORE
    AND
        ISSUE_STS IN ('C', 'N', 'I', 'D')
    AND
        ENT_STAMP BETWEEN @DtFrom AND @DtTo
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    -- ...
    WHERE
        ISSUE_TYPE = 'T1'
    AND
        ISSUE_STS IN ('C', 'N', 'I', 'D')
    AND
        ENT_STAMP BETWEEN @DtFrom AND @DtTo
END
```

Then just pass null if you want to return all stores.

> EDIT, second option (test it before deploy):

```
   -- ...
    WHERE
        ISSUE_TYPE = 'T1'
    AND
        ISNULL(TXT_03,'') = CASE WHEN @STORE IS NULL THEN ISNULL(TXT_03,'')
                                ELSE @STORE
                                END
    AND
        ISSUE_STS IN ('C', 'N', 'I', 'D')
    AND
        ENT_STAMP BETWEEN @DtFrom AND @DtTo
```

Comment: This has a 50% chance of using an inappropriate execution plan. The execution plan is created and cached the *first* time the stored procedure is called

Comment: Thanks for this I will give this a go

Comment: @TitoPaterson if you do, the next question will be "why is this slow". *Why* are you trying to use a stored procedure in this case? Why not a view or a function? Why not a LINQ query?

Comment: I am not going to be running this myself on a daily basis. I will be giving it to others to use in my organization

Comment: @panagiotiskanavos : You're only right about the version using a CASE statement. The version with an IF statement is a perfectly valid way to go, both SELECTs will be given different execution plans (SQL statements get plans, TSQL stored procedures don't).